# When DocuSign will be ready for Chrome 80 ? - sameSite cookie change

Tags: docusignapi

We use DocuSign embedded sending feature. Basically we create envelope through API and then display to a sender an iFrame window with envelope sending view where he can do final configuration and click the send button.

> Google is introducing a change from Chrome 80 that is well described
>   here:
>   https://blog.chromium.org/2019/10/developers-get-ready-for-new.html
>   and here: https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5633521622188032

Long story short: Any cookie that requests SameSite=None but is not marked Secure will be rejected by Chrome starting from version 80.

Currently we can see that DocuSign is not ready for this change. We see warnings in console about same site cookie. 
When we change Chrome experimental flags: "SameSiteby default cookies"  and "Cookies without SameSite must be secure" to enabled (as it will be set in Chrome 80) the iFrame stops working completely.

The questions are:

- Is DocuSign aware of the change introducing in Google Chrom v 80?
- Is DocuSign planning to develope neccessary changes so the iFrame will be working?
- When those changes will be delivered?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Rafal, we were not aware of this issue. We are going to take a look at Chrome 80 (which is releasing in a month) and see what the issues are and get back to you with a resolution soon.

Comment: Happy to discuss issues here! Please feel free to reach out on Twitter @rowan_m

Comment: we're working on it and hope to have a fix over the weekend

Comment: @InbarGazit Hi, it doesn't seem like this issue has been fixed yet? I'm just working on diagnosing the issue with somebody else's codebase for a company and this issue seems to be stopping the docusign iframe from working properly.
[See output here when attempting to load iframe](https://i.imgur.com/YwvD6BY.png)
I can confirm that the exact link being used for the iframe works perfectly when navigating to it manually. Any update on progress with this issue?

Comment: where you trying in production or demo/sandbox?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered redirecting to DocuSign instead of using an iFrame? Redirecting is recommended.

I just turned on the Chrome experiments mentioned in the article you referenced and the Signing Ceremony worked fine when I redirected to it.

Comment: Yes, I know it will work that way, but my company insists on having it embedded into our page